# How to access local css files in external HTML File

Tags: titanium

I load some external files form the web in webview, but now I won't to improve the loading time and save all css und images on device.

My folder is `/Ressources/assets/themes/....`

In html file I try everything from simply `assets/...` to `file:///Ressources....`

What is the right way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `app://` prefix.

Answer (score 2):

we have to use prefix  `app://`
For a example if you want to include style.css which is inside of  folder mycss

```
app://mycss/style.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this will may help you

Was there ever a solution to this problem? I'm having it as well. I tried 4 methods of linking:

../css/style.css

/css/style.css

app://css/style.css

file:///css/style.css

Answer (score 0):

app://Resources/css/style.css works for me.

Using 3.1.1.GA